# How to add two CSS classes with transition property to one HTML element?

Tags: html, css, transition

I have two different classes that I append to various html elements in different configurations to achieve different transition options. eg. only `color` transition, only `border` transition, or both `color` and `border` transition. When I add two classes for one html element that have the `transition` property, **only the one** transition property works.

In the sample below, in the `button B` the `color` transition does not work. I know that I can create `transition: color .1s, border .1s` etc. for each element separately, but with class-approach it would be much less code.

```css
button {
  display:block;
  border:solid 3px #33aaff;
  background-color:white;
  color:#33aaff;
  margin:5px;
  font-size:22px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.anim-color{
  color:#33aaff;
  transition:color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.anim-color:hover{
  color:#ff55aa;
}

.anim-border{
  border:solid 3px #33aaff;
  transition:border .2s .1s ease-in-out;
}

.anim-border:hover{
  border:solid 3px #ff55aa;
}
```

```html
<button class="anim-color">button A</button>
<button class="anim-color anim-border">button B</button>
```

Comment: It's for the same reason you can't specify two `height`s and expect the browser to add them together. CSS classes don't add up, they overwrite. You can try putting `transition: all` if that'd help you here.

Comment: When it comes to comma-separated properties, it would be nice if CSS add up values :) `transition:all` causes transition effect for all properties when the page is loaded. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a CSS property twice, then one value will override the other. It will never be treated in an additive way.

You need to apply all the pieces of the value at once.

You can either do that **all the time**:

```
button {
    transition: color .1s, border .1s
}
```

or **only when the classes are combined**:

```
.anim-color.anim-border {
    transition: color .1s, border .1s
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally the SASS did the trick to me. It concatenates the separate `transition` properties' values into one comma-separated value.

```
@mixin transitions($action, $compositions...){
  $list:();
  @each $getComposition in $compositions{
    $list: append($list, map-get($getComposition, transition), comma);
    @each $prop, $value in map-get($getComposition, before) {
      #{inspect($prop)}: #{inspect($value)};
    }
  }
  transition: $list;
  &:#{$action}{
    @each $getComposition in $compositions{
      @each $prop, $value in map-get($getComposition, after) {
        #{inspect($prop)}: #{inspect($value)};
      }
    }
  }
}

//The transition templates
$anim-border: (
  before:(border:solid 1px #33aaff),
  after:(border:solid 4px #ff55aa),
  transition:border .1s .4s ease-in-out
);

$anim-colors: (
  before:(background-color:white, color:#33aaff),
  after:(background-color:yellow, color:#ff55aa),
  transition:(background-color .2s ease-in-out, color .3s .2s ease-in-out)
);

//Add the 'hover' selector and comma separated list of chosen transition templates
.button-a{
  @include transitions(hover,$anim-colors, $anim-border);
}

.button-b{
  @include transitions(hover,$anim-colors);
}

.button-c{
  @include transitions(hover,$anim-border);
}
```

And the compiled CSS:

```
.button-a {
  background-color: white;
  color: #33aaff;
  border: solid 1px #33aaff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.3s 0.2s ease-in-out, border 0.1s 0.4s ease-in-out; }
  .button-a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #ff55aa;
    border: solid 4px #ff55aa; }

.button-b {
  background-color: white;
  color: #33aaff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.3s 0.2s ease-in-out; }
  .button-b:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #ff55aa; }

.button-c {
  border: solid 1px #33aaff;
  transition: border 0.1s 0.4s ease-in-out; }
  .button-c:hover {
    border: solid 4px #ff55aa; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try this

```css
     button {
   display:block;
   border:solid 3px #33aaff;
   background-color:white;
   color:#33aaff;
   margin:5px;
   font-size:22px;
   cursor:pointer;
  transition: 1s;
   -webkit-transition: 1s;
 }

 .anim-color{
   color:#33aaff;
 }

 .anim-color:hover{
   color:#ff55aa;
 }

 .anim-border{
   border:solid 3px #33aaff;
 }

 .anim-border:hover{
   border:solid 3px #ff55aa;
 }
```

```html
<button class="anim-color">button A</button>
<button class="anim-color anim-border">button B</button>
```